# how to add page numbers to a pdf file (being printed)

Tags: windows-8, pdf, printing

I frequently take prints of PDF, but the source doesnt add page numbers to them. Is there a way to add page numbers to a pdf file (it is not editable)?
Or if page numbers can be inserted anyway during print.

Answer (score 2):

Open the link and just upload your pdf files in it, it will add the page number for you.
[Add page numbers to PDF files](https://tools.pdf24.org/en/add-page-numbers-to-pdf)
[Add page numbers to PDF](https://pdf.io/page-numbers/)

There are many tools or online tools you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Software Answer : Use Adobe Acrobat to open the document, make a change, and save it with a different name.  Acrobat costs money, so if you want a free solution, Google "Adobe Acrobat Alternatives".  You may be able to edit it directly in Google Docs, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Low-tech answer : Determine the orientation of the paper tray compared to the output printing, and print twice.  Steps : In pen, write "Example text" on the top page in the paper tray and remember the orientation.  Print out one page with the desired heading.  There are four possible orientations for the paper, so the text and heading are probably not oriented the way you want, but you can use the first attempt to figure out which orientation works.

Next, print out all of the "blank" pages with the desired headings.  Gather up the pages, insert them with the correct orientation, and print out the document on them.

Please note that some printers will jam if you re-use paper like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **A-PDF Number** utility, it's *simple but useful for adding page numbers to existing PDF files*. You can customize position, text color & prefix of the page numbers.

[image]

Free Download at: http://www.a-pdf.com/number/index.htm

Comment: The web site indicates that this is compatible with Windows from v98 through Vista.  Can you verify that it also works with current versions of Windows?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 It functions correclty on Windows 7 and Windows 8, it should run on Windows 10 but I don't have installed Win10.

Comment: yeh it works on Win10 - only prints numbers at the bottom. I'm guessing the purchased version will let you chose more places to place them.